# What should be do about cross postings?

Tags: discussion

I refer to this question, which was posted (or cross posted) on electrical engineering, and our site.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/150511/how-can-i-measure-the-brightness-of-a-led

Should we allow it on both sites? Should we force the OP to pick one site or the other? Or should we exclude it from both sites because it was cross posted?

Most SE sites discourage cross posting.

Comment: Not sure *what* to do, but I'm trying to talk to the EE mods to see what they think about it. We've got one of them (Dave Tweed) right here on Engineering, though, which is nice and could be advantageous.

Comment: @HDE226868  Make it two EE.SE mods.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Proof I should do some more research. Awesome that you're here.

Answer (score 7):

The general response is [**DO NOT CROSS-POST**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu), for a variety of reasons. But that's not the issue here; the issue is that the damage (exaggeration!?) is already done.

A more relevant Meta.SE post is [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183362/cross-posting-questions-between-so-and-infant-beta-se-site). Quoting Shog9,

> You should try to avoid this.
>
> My recommendation is: ask on Magento first. If you don't get a useful answer there after a reasonable amount of time (a couple of days at minimum), then post a question on Stack Overflow informed by your experience on Magento

So that's SE policy.

In our specific case, I agree - post the question here first, *then*, if no answer is to be found after some time, you can *maybe* consider posting it on another SE after you close it here first.

In this case, the question was asked here first (good) and received some good answers within 24 hours (good), and the OP accepted an answer (also good). The OP then posted the question on Electrical Engineering (bad) where it received a couple answers (good) *but* leaves the two questions unrelated (bad). It's also surprising, since the answers seemed to address the OP's issue, although he did comment

> Thanks, your explanation is what we are planning on doing. But we need define a system for test, validation, as well as manufacturing. We have one of the exact instruments you have recommended

Which leads me to think the issue is not resolved, in which case that should be articulated in the question here.

I don't think we should get rid of the question here, but we *definitely* shouldn't delete it from both sites. The best thing to do would be to get in touch with the guys over on Electrical Engineering, which I'm currently attempting (via chat, because I don't have an Electrical Engineering account) but have so far not succeeded. But if Dave Tweed (mod on EE and active user here) could help us out, that would be great. . .

Comment: There are three reasonably-good answers on each site, so the obvious solution would be to "merge" them, but AFAIK, cross-site merging doesn't exist. And migrating the one from EE to Engineering first won't work, because the answers won't migrate with it. I don't know if there's any good answer to this. Perhaps there will be more options once we move out of private beta?

Comment: @DaveTweed I forget what new options (if any) we'll have when we move out of private beta. At that point, answers *should* be able to migrate with the question, though the answerers will lose rep if they don't have accounts here.

Comment: @DaveTweed - Answers should migrate with a post. But you're correct in that the three questions would need to be migrated to one site and then merged.

Comment: @GlenH7: I may have misinterpreted what I was seeing, but some time ago I got the impression that answers failed to migrate if the person who posted the answer didn't already have an account on the destination site. Do you know whether or not this is the case?

Comment: @DaveTweed The only hiccups I've seen are when a migrated question gets closed on the target site.  When it's closed, the target site tries to ship the post back to the source site.  I don't believe any answers generated on the target site will migrate on the rejected post.  Similarly, if the question is too old to migrate back to the source, then the answers from the source site will be deleted and the question will become locked on the target site.  We frequently get those on Programmers from old SO migrations.  Usually a mod has to go in and delete everything off since it's now locked.

Comment: @DaveTweed The answers migrate over, which means that people can lose rep (and get annoyed at it). If the receiving site rejects it, the question can go back, with the answers from the other site.